# Auth0 Invalid Compact JWS

Tags: reactjs, oauth, auth0

Perhaps there may just be issues with the service?

Im using a simple React SPA and express graphql backend.

My Auth provider looks like:

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain="mydomain"
  clientId="clientid"
  redirectUri={window.location.origin}
  audience="test"
>
  <App />
</Auth0Provider>
```

I am then using getAccessTokenSilently, i have tried with and without adding audience here:

```
   const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
      audience: 'test',
    });
```

This returns me a JWE / opaque token that is unusable.

The audience on my API is the same but regardless i cant get past opaque access token from the front end call so it seems the problem is here. This is with a default simple setup for Single Page Application, and an API where the identifier is set to 'test'

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I also had this issue yesterday and managed to solve it by verifying the code against their latest samples, updated my answer if it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

1. Verify which auth0 script version you are using
2. Check that all auth0 methods keys match your version by verifying an appropriate auth0 sample code, e.g. [vanilla JS](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs)

### Details

I had this issue using [vanilla JS auth0 sample](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs), but in any case, I also forward a [Github answer of an auth0 member](https://github.com/auth0/node-oauth2-jwt-bearer/issues/69#issuecomment-1191185036) regarding React usage:

> When you login to Auth0 and don't specify an Audience, you will get an
> [opaque access token](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens#opaque-access-tokens). It looks like a regular JWT, but actually it's a
> self contained encrypted JWT. The only way to validate an opaque token
> is to call the server that issued the token, in this case the
> /userinfo endpoint.
>
> In order to get an [access token JWT](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens#jwt-access-tokens), you need to [create a custom api](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/auth0-overview/set-up-apis).
> Then use this as the audience in your react app to login… [code in the [Github thread](https://github.com/auth0/node-oauth2-jwt-bearer/issues/69#issuecomment-1191185036)]

In my case, I already had the proper `audience` value in both methods: `createAuth0Client` and `auth` for verification, but I was using an older CDN version ([v1.13](https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0-spa-js/1.13/auth0-spa-js.production.js)).

I firstly noticed the following:

1. in *DevTools\Network*, upon user authentication the returned `access_token` in [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) had an empty payload `eyJ…..6g2LPYaj3WGTjMpj.…` with a header:

   ```
   {
     "alg": "dir",
     "enc": "A256GCM",
     "iss": "https://my-auth-url.uk.auth0.com/"
   }
   ```
2. according to [their audience docs](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/get-access-tokens#control-access-token-audience):

   > In only one specific instance, access tokens can have multiple target audiences. This **requires** that your custom API's signing algorithm is set to **RS256**. (...) If you specify an audience of your custom API identifier and a scope of `openid`, then the resulting access token's **`aud` claim will be an array** rather than a string, and the access token will be valid for both your custom API and for the `/userinfo` endpoint
3. I verified that the version I was using (v1.13) had a few different parameters from the newest version (v2.0), so I started checking my entire script against their vanilla JS sample
4. then I logged the result of the token creation:

   ```
    auth0Client = await auth0.createAuth0Client({
      domain: config.domain,
      client_id: config.clientId,
      authorizationParams: {
        audience: config.audience
      }
    });
    console.log('> auth0 obj', auth0Client);
   ```
5. which returned an `undefined` client id in several of its values, e.g.:

   ```
   "orgHintCookieName": "auth0.undefined.organization_hint",
   "isAuthenticatedCookieName": "auth0.undefined.is.authenticated"
   ```
6. so the **main culprit causing the "Invalid Compact JWS" error was the client id** in **createAuth0Client** — after I changed it from `client_id` to `clientId`, the token returned upon authentication started using the **RS256** algorithm:

   ```
    {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT",
    "kid": "w4kIQ24N6SxmN-ELskX_b"
    }
   ```
7. the payload was no longer empty and had both endpoints mentioned in the docs:

   ```
    "aud": [
      "https://my-auth-url.uk.auth0.com/api/v2/",
      "https://my-auth-url.uk.auth0.com/userinfo"
    ],
   ```